# Double FOR loop and FileOutputStream

Tags: android, outputstream, fileoutputstream

In this portion of my app, I have a database which is absorbing data from my light sensor.  It has a RowID associated with each row.

In the background I have an AsyncTaskRunner which is reading that table and writing each row to a CSV file.  It should loop through the entire table as data is being written to it, looking for all rows for the current TID that have not been copied to CSV.  THen it should write the row values to CSV and go back and mark the row as copied.

THe first loop should come in where no it goes back to the database cursor and looks for the next row which has not been copied to the CSV file.  After each copy to CSV it should evaluate the size of that CSV file to make sure it is not full.  If not Full then should go back to the Database cursor and look for the next row to write to the CSV file.  If isfull then it should loop back to LoopMain and start over creating a new CSV file to write to.

While the full method is not complete yet, I am at the part where the row data is suposed to be written to the CSV file.  At the moment, it does not write to it.  Before I made this method a For Loop, it did, now it does not.  I can not figure out what has changed.  I have inserted all of these Log comments to follow the method as it passes values, receives values and then does an action to see where it is failing.  THe method passes the section where it is to write to the CSV file and continues on, but the file is empty.

```
public void lightloop(){

    //Loop Main
    int loopcounter;
    LoopMain: for(loopcounter = 0; loopcounter < 4; loopcounter++ ){
        Log.d(CSV, "lightloop loopcounter = " + loopcounter);

    String CSVFinalFileName=createlightcsv();
       Log.w(CSV, "LightLoop, CSVFinalFileName = " + CSVFinalFileName);


      //Loop 2

       Loop2: for(int useless=1; useless > 0; useless++ ){
       String flightRowId = evaluateLightTable(filenamePrefix); //returns the rowid of the first line not transmitted
          Log.w(CSV, "LightLoop, flightRowId = " + flightRowId);
          Log.d(CSV, "filefullBoolean " + useless);

       if(flightRowId != null){
           Log.w(CSV, "LightLoop flightRowId is NOT NULL");
           //write row to csv
              //Get all row values and put into a string
              String lightRowValues=fetchLightRowData(flightRowId, filenamePrefix);
                 Log.w(CSV, "lightLoop, lightRowValues are " + lightRowValues);
              //Append that data to the CSV file
                Log.w(CSV, "Opening File Output Stream");
                try {
                    FileOutputStream csvfos = mContext.openFileOutput(CSVFinalFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                OutputStreamWriter sensorCSVWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(csvfos);        
                try {
                    sensorCSVWriter.append("LIGHT " + lightRowValues);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        /**     try {
                    sensorCSVWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  **/

           //mark row as transmitted
                SQLDatabase updatelightrow = new SQLDatabase(mContext);
                updatelightrow.open();
                SQLDatabase.updateLightRow(flightRowId);
                updatelightrow.close();

            }// end If rowid is not null


           //evaluate size of csv
                Boolean filefull = CsvStreamer.checkFileSize(CSVFinalFileName);

                if(!filefull){
                    //return to cursor
                    Log.d(CSV, "lightloop, File is NOT full");
                    break Loop2;

                }else{
                    Log.d(CSV, "lightloop, File IS full");
                    //file is full. close it, 

                    //transmit it, 

                    //open a new one

                    //goto CSV table and mark it transmitted

                    break LoopMain;
                }
       }//end Loop2

}//end LoopMain

}
```

Can anyone see why this is failing to write to the File?

Comment: I guess it does not even compile (unless you have a class field named `csvfos`). If you have one, it is most likely not initialized.

Comment: I did not say it does not compile, did I....

Comment: So your class does have a field `csvfos`. Please show how it is declared and initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The csvfos is not in the same scope. I assume the class has a property called csvfos also, hence the method is accessing the property and not the csvfos variable created in the try catch.

Try changing

```
try 
{
    FileOutputStream csvfos = mContext.openFileOutput(CSVFinalFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
{
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

to

```
FileOutputStream csvfos = null;

try 
{
    csvfos  = mContext.openFileOutput(CSVFinalFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
{
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: hmmm I will give it a try and come back.. THere was a separate method that initialized the cvsfos and then opened the output stream.  This functioned well prior to putting the for loop in place.  I wonder now if that entire method just became garbage and no longer initializs the cvsfos?  I will come back and comment after testing.  Thanks